# Make Log Scale Histogram Plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot data I have as a histogram on a log scale from 0 to 1. I have tried just importing my data and plotting like so:

```
allelefreq <- read.table("allelefreqs.txt", header = TRUE)
allelefreq <- sapply(allelefreq, as.numeric) #convert to numbers
hist(allelefreq, xlim = range(0:1))
```

But this just shows me a single large bar at 0 and then empty space for the rest of the plot and isn't log scale obviously.

I have also tried using ggplot to do this but am not successful. Part of the problem might be that I have an enormous amount of data that consists of very small numbers near 0 and I was thinking that smaller bins would help solve this problem because they would be separated more.

I dont know if it is possible to create bins that are very small on a histogram or cut the y axis at some point to show everything. But does anybody know how to plot this?

My data is simple and looks like this (though with about 10,000 samples):

```
AlleleFreq
0.001556
0.001985
0.000036
0.000024
0.000036
0.000024
0.001126
0.000012
0.000012
0.000012
0.000012
0.000012
0.000012
0.000012
0.501322
```

Comment: What does it mean to you have a "histogram on a log scale from 0 to 1"?

Comment: you've extracted data from a histogram? Also your sample data covers many orders of magnitude. I'd try to subset the data first. btw it doesn't really make sense to set your xlim to (0,1) in this context.

Comment: I would like the X axis to be on plotted on a log scale where the maximum value is 1. And no I haven't extracted the data from a histogram but I have data that I would like to plot as a histogram.

Comment: well that clears things up.

Comment: Cool. Yeah I suppose my code being wrong might be  a bit misleading.

Comment: So if you throw a histogram at a large numeric vector and it is spiky...you should use that to subset your data. logarithms at this point would only obfuscate anything you're trying to discover.

Comment: So is there no way to plot all of this data on a single plot? I imagine it wouldn't be all that bad on a log scale if the first few bins were 0.00001, 0.00002, 0.0003 and so on and eventually jumping up a log to 0.001...

Comment: You can just do `hist(log(allelefreq))` instead of `hist(allelefreq)`. Also, the histogram function will set the x bounds on its own, so I would suggest only adjusting those after you run the hist function without x bounds first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone looks back here for an answer. This is the code I used to solve this problem:

```
allelefreq <- read.table("allelefreqs.txt", header = TRUE)
hist(log(allelefreq$AlleleFreq), xlim = c(-15,1), breaks=100)
```